# Oracle stored procedure using temp tables

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, temp-tables

The main idea: I want create 3 tables (as temp tables) with some selects, take 1 and 2 and compare.

Result insert to 3 table.

My procedure looks like:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CHECK_PARAMS
AS 
TYPE row IS RECORD (id NUMBER,         
                    count_id NUMBER ); 
TYPE my_table_type IS TABLE OF row;

first my_table_type;
second my_table_type;
third my_table_type;    
BEGIN
  SELECT id, count_id bulk collect -- GOOD SELECT
  INTO first
  FROM 
    (SELECT test1.A_ID id, 
            COUNT(test1.A_ID) count_id
     FROM MY_OTHER_TABLE1 test1, 
          MY_OTHER_TABLE2 test2
     WHERE test1.A_ID = test2.A_ID
     GROUP BY test1.A_ID);

  SELECT id, count_id bulk collect -- GOOD SELECT
  INTO first
  FROM 
    (SELECT test1.A_ID id, 
            COUNT(test1.A_ID) count_id
     FROM MY_OTHER_TABLE3 test1, 
          MY_OTHER_TABLE4 test2
     WHERE test1.A_ID = test2.A_ID
     GROUP BY test1.A_ID);

  SELECT id, count_id bulk collect -- ORACLE CAN'T FIND MY TEMP TABLES
  INTO third
  FROM frist, second; -- **HERE I GOT ERROR: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist**
```

What's wrong?

Comment: One issue is that you have a typo in the final select. You have `FROM frist` instead of `FROM first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the types outside of the procedure

```
create TYPE t_row as object  (id NUMBER,         
                    count_id NUMBER ); 

create TYPE my_table_type IS TABLE OF t_row;
```

and than you have to use `table`

```
SELECT id, count_id bulk collect -- ORACLE CAN'T FIND MY TEMP TABLES
  INTO third
  FROM table(first), table(second);
```

Comment: If I don't want to create new types. We have other variant? I need to save some select to local variable. What about cursor's?

Comment: I would just write the whole thing into one select statement. If there is no step between, there is no reason to make more than one statement out of it.

Comment: Ye, I did, but I want resolve this problem for understanding and using next time. And next time is now)